# GFortran equivalent of ieee_exceptions

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I am trying to write a program that will stop whenever an invalid operation is performed, no matter how it is compiled with GFortran. With ifort I could do something like this:

```
use ieee_exceptions
....
logical      :: halt
....
call ieee_get_halting_mode(IEEE_USUAL,halt)
call ieee_set_halting_mode(IEEE_USUAL,.True.)
....
! Something that may stop the program
....
call ieee_set_halting_mode(IEEE_USUAL,halt)
```

Does GFortran have a module similar to ifort's `ieee_exceptions`? Or even better is there a way of stopping the halting mode without knowing how the program will be compiled or which compiler will be used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GFortran supports the ieee_exceptions module as of the GCC 5 release.

If you're stuck on an older GFortran release, a workaround would be to implement functions in C/asm that get/set the FP trapping status register and call those from Fortran.

PS.: GFortran does have a switch (-fpe-trap) for globally enabling traps for FP exceptions, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/Debugging-Options.html . But, since you explicitly said "no matter how it is compiled with gfortran", I guess you don't want to use that.

Comment: Actually, it appears that this is now part of gfortran 5: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran/News#gfortran_5