# Setup NaN traps in shared library

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes, gfortran

I have a little problem with NaN traps while I use ctypes and shared library. The library was written in Fortran and consists of the subroutine which has the line 'division by zero':

```
nantest.f90

subroutine nantest
    real :: a, b, c
    a = 0.
    b = 0.
    c = a/b
    print *, c,a,b
end subroutine nantest

program main
    call nantest
end program main
```

I made a shared library from it using the options:

```
gfortran -o nantest.os -c -g -fbacktrace -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fPIC nantest.f90
gfortran -o libnantest.so -shared nantest.os
```

Then I load this library right from the Python script:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL('./libnantest.so')
lib.nantest_()
```

and it gives me the output without any exception:

```
          NaN   0.00000000       0.00000000
```

What is wrong? Is it ctypes or compiler options problem?
BTW, when I performed the direct execution of 'nantest' program built with the same compiler options I got what I wanted:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.
Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F4D08B6FE08
#1  0x7F4D08B6EF90
#2  0x7F4D087C04AF
#3  0x40080D in nantest_ at nantest.f90:7
#4  0x4008B9 in MAIN__ at nantest.f90:14
Floating point exception
```

So, how I can get the NaN-exception in the shared library case?
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The Python runtime sets its own FPE mode. You may try the Fortran 2003 procedures to set FPE exceptions at the exact place you need. They are in the intrinsic module `IEEE_EXCEPTIONS`, for example procedure `ieee_get_halting_mode()`. See also [GFortran equivalent of ieee_exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541189/gfortran-equivalent-of-ieee-exceptions)

The `-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow` is only useful when compiling a Fortran program.

Or use the Python features (https://docs.python.org/2/library/fpectl.html) to find out whether any floating point exceptions are signalling, but I don't know whether the interface between Python and the library preserves them.